# Extracting multiple submatrices in Python

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to extract multiple submatrices if my sparse matrix has multiple regions of non-zero values.

For example,
Say I have the following matrix:

```
x = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,1,1,0,0,0],
             [0,1,1,0,0,1],
             [0,0,0,0,1,1],
             [0,0,0,0,1,0])
```

Then I need to be able to extract the regions with non-zero values, ie

```
x_1 = [[1,1]
       [1,1]]
```

and

```
x_2 = [[0,1],
       [1,1],
       [1,0]]
```

I have been using np.where() to find the indices of non-zero values and returning the region for only one submatrix, but how can I extend this to all possible subregions in my sparse matrix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Procedure:

1. Delete leading and trailing rows and columns with all zeros. (Not middle ones)
2. Find all empty rows and columns and split matrix on these indices. This creates a list of matrices
3. For each newly created matrix repeat the procedure recursively until no further splitting is possible

Code:

```
def delrc(arr):
    while True:     # delete leading rows with all zeros
    if np.all(arr[0]==0):
        arr=np.delete(arr,0,axis=0)
    else: break
    while True:     # delete trailing rows with all zeros
    if np.all(arr[-1]==0):
        arr=np.delete(arr,-1,axis=0)
    else: break
    while True:     # delete leading cols with all zeros
    if np.all(arr[:,0]==0):
        arr=np.delete(arr,0,axis=1)
    else: break
    while True:     # delete trailing cols with all zeros
    if np.all(arr[:,-1]==0):
        arr=np.delete(arr,-1,axis=1)
    else: break
    return arr

def rcsplit(arr):
    if np.all(arr==0): return []    # if all zeros return
    global  res
    arr = delrc(arr)        # delete leading/trailing rows/cols with all zeros
    print arr
    indr = np.where(np.all(arr==0,axis=1))[0]
    indc = np.where(np.all(arr==0,axis=0))[0]
    if not indr and not indc:   # If no further split possible return
    res.append(arr)
    return
    arr=np.delete(arr,indr,axis=0)  #delete empty rows in between non empty rows
    arr=np.delete(arr,indc,axis=1)  #delete empty cols in between non empty cols
    arr=np.split(arr,indc,axis=1)   # split on empty (all zeros) cols 
    print arr
    arr2=[]
    for i in arr:
    z=delrc(i)  
    arr2.extend(np.split(z,indr,axis=0))   # split on empty (all zeros) rows
    for i in arr2:
    rcsplit(np.array(i))        # recursive split again no further splitting is possible

if __name__=="__main__":

    import numpy as np 
    res = []   
    arr = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,1,0,0,0],
        [0,1,1,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,1,1],
        [0,0,0,0,1,0]])
    rcsplit(arr)
    for i in res: print i
```

Comment: thank you but I am getting an error with the global definition:

    NameError: global name 'res' is not defined

Comment: It also doesn't seem to be working for the general case of any two submatrices.

Comment: @alvarezcl, You need to define `res=[]` in the main function first. I've uploaded the actual full code. Try it. Also, it works for any case of two sub-matrices. I've tested it first for many cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use built-ins for this.

```
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import find_objects, label
from scipy.ndimage import generate_binary_structure as gbs

import numpy as np

# create array
x = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,1,1,0,0,0],
             [0,1,1,0,0,1],
             [0,0,0,0,1,1],
             [0,0,0,0,1,0]])

# define labeling structure to inlcude adjacent (including diagonal) cells
struc = gbs(2,2)

# generate array of labeled sections labels
x2, numlabels = label(x,struc)

# pull out first group of "ones"
xy1 = find_objects(x2==1)[0]

# pull out second group of "ones"
xy2 = find_objects(x2==2)[0]
```

Now test:

```
>>> x[xy1]
    array([[1, 1],
           [1, 1]])

>>> x[xy2]
    array([[0, 1],
           [1, 1],
           [1, 0]])
```

Voila!  If you want to pull out all subsections you can iterate over , which tells you how many different groups you have within the array.

Comment: This is actually better solution than the accepted one IMO.